# Programmatically add a link to the JavaScript code on the page

Tags: 2013, development

It is possible to programmatically add automatically script to the page SharePoint, i.e. the **Content Editor** is followed by a link URL to file script, i was only text example?

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp:7000/sites/test"))
        {
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            SPFile page = web.GetFile("SitePages/Test.aspx");
            page.CheckOut();
            using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpmgr = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
            {
                XmlElement p = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("p");
                p.InnerText = "Hello World";
                ContentEditorWebPart cewp = new ContentEditorWebPart
                {
                    Content = p
                };
                wpmgr.AddWebPart(cewp, "Header", 0);
            }
            page.CheckIn(String.Empty);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, then yes you can.  You can put all of your CSS/HTML/JavaScript into a TXT file and reference that file in your CEWP.  This is considered best practice to do it this way anyways.  Just edit the CEWP and put the URL to the text file in the reference.  Now you just modify the txt file and it will change all of your CEWPs you are using to reference your custom file.